# Adding points to a list within class

Tags: c#, list, class

trying to make a dart point counter for school via a provided uml. Ive gotten only so far as to add the players names but im now stuck on scorekeeping! The way i done it here only adds to the score for 1 player but then overwrites the list for the second one.

You get prompted how many players to add, then add the players names, but i cant get past on how to get each player their individual scoretracking. player1 should throw 3 arrows and get points 0-60 on each arrow, then its player2 turn to do the same. First person over 501 wins, so i need to keep track on score for individual players but dont know how :/

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ThrowDart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Game game = new Game();
            game.PlayGame();

        }
    }

    public class Game
    {

        private List<Player> personer = new List<Player>();

        public void AddPlayer(int Players)
        {
            int howMany = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Players; i++)
            {
                personer.Add(new Player());

            }

            foreach (Player player in personer)
            {
                howMany = howMany + 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Please name player " + howMany + ":");
                player.Name = Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }

        public void PlayGame()
        {
        start:


            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to DartGame");
            Console.WriteLine("How many players would you like to add?");
            int antalSpelare;
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (Int32.TryParse(input, out antalSpelare))
            {


                AddPlayer(antalSpelare);

            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Numbers only for adding players, please.");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                goto start;
            }





            for (int i = 0; i < personer.Count; i++)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("points for player " + personer[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("First arrow points: ");
                int throw1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Second arrow points:");
                int throw2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Third arrow points:");
                int throw3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Arrows arrows = new Arrows(throw1, throw2, throw3);


                foreach (var item in arrows.arrowList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }

    public class Player : Game
    {


        public List<int> arrowList = new List<int>();

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Player()
        { 

        }


        public string player(string name)
        {

            return "";
        }

        public int CalculatePoints()
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < arrowList.Count; i++)
            {

            }
            return 0;

        }

        public void AddArrows(string Arrows)
        { 

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }


    }

    public class Arrows : Player
    {

        private int arrowOne;
        private int arrowTwo;
        private int arrowThree;



        public Arrows(int arrowOne, int arrowTwo, int arrowThree)
        {

            this.arrowOne = arrowOne;
            this.arrowTwo = arrowTwo;
            this.arrowThree = arrowThree;

            arrowList.Add(arrowOne);
            arrowList.Add(arrowTwo);
            arrowList.Add(arrowThree);


        }

        public int GetScore()
        {



            return 0;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString() + "ToString override 2";
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: List<Tuple<Player,int>> to keep the scores per player.

Comment: `Player` inherits from `Game`? and `Arrow` inherits from `Player` :S You have inheritance all muddled up.

Comment: Just following the uml provided at the start of this task :/

Comment: @user3296768 I believe Jamiec is right. Your class hierarchy doesn't make much sense. Are you sure you read the UML correctly? I think you accidentally read the composition/containment arrows as inheritance.

Comment: calmly puts my palm over my face! thanks :)

Comment: still stuck on how to implement the running score though :(

Comment: As others have said, the inheritance of classes doesn't seem right. Game should contain instances of Player, and players instances of Arrows. Once you've fixed that it should be a lot clearer. If not, re-upload what you've got and people should be able to help.